# How to integrate NextJs with Java Spring Boot SSO using Apereo CAS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, next.js, spring-security

Our system is comprises of:

1. NextJS Front End
2. NextJS Back End
3. Java Spring Boot SSO using Apereo CAS.

We would like to integrate our current system to use Apereo CAS for our new SSO.
The project mostly consist on SSO logins only and will not be related to any other module on the current system.

NextJS + Java Spring Boot Developer For Library System
Our system is comprises of:

1. NextJS Front End
2. NextJS Back End
3. Java Spring Boot SSO using Apereo CAS.

Comment: Cool, good luck! What have you tried so far and what happened? See [ask].